# Trigonometric Triangle Equality

Tags: inequality

$A, B, C$ are the angles of a  triangle  then  $tan^2(A/2)+tan^2(B/2)+tan^2(C/2)$ is
 always greater than what integral value.

Comment: I don't think the answer is 0 because the options are different

Comment: $0$ is clearly a correct answer, since the three summands are non-negative, and cannot all be $0$. What work have you done on this problem?

Comment: Options are 1,2,0.5,3^(1/2)

Comment: Do you know Jensen's Inequality?

Comment: Maybe you can try substituting $A/2 = \pi / 6 + \alpha$, $B/2 = \pi / 6 + \beta$, $C/2 = \pi / 6 - \alpha - \beta$ in the expression and see what that expands to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $A,B,C$ are the angles of a $\triangle.$ So Here $$\displaystyle 0<\frac{A}{2},\frac{B}{2},\frac{C}{2}<\frac{\pi}{2}$$.

Now Using $\bf{A.M\geq G.M}\;,$ We Get

So we get  $$\displaystyle \frac{\tan^2 \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)+\tan^2 \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)}{2}\geq \sqrt{\tan^2 \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cdot \tan^2 \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)} = \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cdot \tan \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\color{red}\checkmark$$

Similarly $$\displaystyle \frac{\tan^2 \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\tan^2 \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)}{2}\geq \sqrt{\tan^2 \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cdot \tan^2 \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)} = \tan \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cdot \tan \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\color{red}\checkmark$$

Similarly $$\displaystyle \frac{\tan^2 \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)+\tan^2 \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)}{2}\geq \sqrt{\tan^2 \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cdot \tan^2 \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)} = \tan \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cdot \tan \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\color{red}\checkmark$$

Now Add all Three, We Get

$$\displaystyle \tan^2\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)+\tan^2\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\tan^2\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\geq \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cdot \tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cdot \tan\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)+\tan\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cdot \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\color{blue}\checkmark\color{blue}\checkmark$$

Now Here $$\displaystyle \frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}=\frac{C}{2}\Rightarrow \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}\right)=\tan \frac{C}{2}$$

So We Get $$\displaystyle \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cdot \tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cdot \tan\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)+\tan\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cdot \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)=1$$

Put into $\color{blue}\checkmark\color{blue}\checkmark\;,$ We Get

$$\displaystyle \tan^2\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)+\tan^2\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\tan^2\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\geq 1$$

Answer (score 3):

Given

$$
\tan^2(A/2) + \tan^2(B/2) + \tan^2(C/2) \ge K
$$

Question is: find $K$.

Write

$$
Q(x,y,z) = \tan^2(x) + \tan^2(y) + \tan^2(z),
$$

such that

$$
x+y+z = P,
$$

where $P$ is a constant. Then

$$
dQ = 2 \frac{\tan(x)}{\cos^2(x)} d x
+ 2 \frac{\tan(y)}{\cos^2(y)} dy
+ 2 \frac{\tan(z)}{\cos^2(z)} dz
$$

But as $x+y+z=P$, we also have

$$
dx+dy+dz = 0
$$

so we obtain

$$
dQ = 2 \left( \frac{\tan(x)}{\cos^2(x)} - \frac{\tan(z)}{\cos^2(z)} \right) d x
+ 2 \left( \frac{\tan(y)}{\cos^2(y)} - \frac{\tan(z)}{\cos^2(z)} \right) dy
$$

We find an extreme value for

$$
\frac{\tan(x)}{\cos^2(x)} - \frac{\tan(z)}{\cos^2(z)} = 0
$$

and

$$
\frac{\tan(y)}{\cos^2(y)} - \frac{\tan(z)}{\cos^2(z)}
$$

So

$$
x = y = z = P/3
$$

Given that

$$
A + B + C = 180^o,
$$

we have

$$
x+y+z = 90^o
$$

So minimum for

$$
x=y=z=30^o
$$

So we obtain

$$
K = 3 \tan^2(30^o) = 1,
$$

whence

$$
\tan^2(A/2) + \tan^2(B/2) + \tan^2(C/2) \ge 1
$$

Comment: Can you give  solution without calculus

Answer (score 3):

Since $A,B,C$ are angles of a triangle, we have $0<\dfrac{A}{2},\dfrac{B}{2},\dfrac{C}{2}<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. For this range of values, $\tan^2 x$ is a convex function. Hence, from Jensen's inequlaity,

$$\tan^2\left(\frac{1}{3}\frac{A}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{B}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{C}{2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{3}\tan^2\frac{A}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\tan^2\frac{B}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\tan^2\frac{C}{2}$$
$$\tan^2\left(\frac{A+B+C}{6}\right) \leq \frac{1}{3}\left(\tan^2\frac{A}{2}+\tan^2\frac{B}{2}+\tan^2\frac{C}{2}\right)$$
Since $A+B+C=\pi$, hence

$$\tan^2\frac{A}{2}+\tan^2\frac{B}{2}+\tan^2\frac{C}{2} \geq 1$$

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Minimum value is achieved when  *symmetric* in $ A,B,C,a,b,c $ equilateral triangle case when they are equal, i.e., $ A = B = C = \pi/3$, which gives to the expression a minimum value

$$ 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 = 1.$$